# dual-role keys, how to on ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard

I have a requirement on my Linux System that I think might be quite a common requirement. But I could not find any similar tool or utility to do this.

What I'd like to do is setup the Escape key in such a way that:

1) Press_Down and Press_Up Escape key within 50ms = Escape.
2) Press_Down (only) the Escape key for longer than 50ms (Press_Up doesn't matter) = Control.

Is this even possible ?

Comment: 1. For what purpose? 2. I think this would probably have to be a scripted event.

Comment: So that I can use my caps lock for both Control and Escape.  Tap for Escape and a longer press for control.

Comment: Any solution to this problem?  (For those that don't know, dual-role keys are a relatively recent innovation in ergonomic keyboard design.)